# TypeError: Can't convert 'builtin_function_or_method' object to str implicitly SOCKETS

Tags: python

I am have recently been learning about networking. So I tried doing an experiment I found on the web. It was a simple server client connection. But I got this error when I tried running my server.py:`

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'builtin_function_or_method' object to str implicitly
```

This is the code for server.py:

```
import socket # socket module

s = socket.socket() # creates socket object "s"
host = socket.gethostname # gets name of local pc
port = 5567 # Reserve a port for the service (numbers are random)
s.bind((host, port)) # connects our host and port number to our socket

s.listen(5) # waits for client connection (5 maximum connections)
while True: # repeats forever
    c, addr = s.accept # Establishes connectd from anyone who tries to connect (c is client object)
    print('Got connection from, '+ addr ) # prints on server gui its connection
    c.send('Thank you for connecting!') # sends client message
    c.close() # stops all connection to current client
```

The error was on line 6.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to *call* your functions:

```
host = socket.gethostname # gets name of local pc
```

and

```
c, addr = s.accept # Establishes connectd from anyone who tries to connect (c is client object)
```

Both `socket.gethostname` and `s.accept` are callables, add `()`:

```
host = socket.gethostname()
```

and

```
c, addr = s.accept()
```

The exception you see is caused by you passing in the `socket.gethostname` function rather than what the function produces.

Comment: Thanks so much and you answered my question so quickly thank you!!